# Facing issue while using for loop in snowflake scripting stored procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I created a stored procedure in snowflake using for loop. Facing the issue while calling the stored procedure. Below is the code.

```
create or replace procedure sp7(iteration_limit integer)
returns integer
language sql
as
$$
declare 
    loop_var integer default 0;
begin
    for loop_var in 1 to iteration_limit do
        execute immediate 'insert into abc(id) values(loop_var)';
    end for;
end;
$$;
```

I am getting the below error.

```
Error:'STATEMENT_ERROR' on line 6 at position 8 : SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 27 (line 100)
invalid identifier 'LOOP_VAR' (line 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a variable that way inside a string literal in SQL Script. The cleanest way to handle this is using a bind variable:

```
create or replace procedure sp7(iteration_limit integer)
returns integer
language sql
as
$$
declare 
    loop_var integer default 0;
begin
    for loop_var in 1 to iteration_limit do
        execute immediate 'insert into abc(id) values(?)' using (loop_var);
    end for;
end;
$$;
create or replace temp table ABC(id int);
call sp7(10);
```

I would be very careful about how many iterations of the loop this performs. If it's just a few it will be okay. If it's even 1000 and each pass through the loop takes a few hundred milliseconds, that will take several minutes just to get through those 1000 rows. It's better to perform inserts in batches.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever possible one should avoid procedural logic whenever a set logic solution is available. Perhaps the [GENERATOR function](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/generator.html) would be a better solution. Here is your example with an arbitrary ceiling of one million rows limited by the passed in stored procedure parameter iteration_limit:

```
insert into abc (id)
select row_number() over(order by 0) as id
from table(generator(rowcount => 1000000))
limit iteration_limit;
```

Answer (score 0):

The dynamic SQL part `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` is completely unnecessary and could be simply fixed with standard `INSERT INTO`:

```
execute immediate 'insert into abc(id) values(loop_var)';
=>
insert into abc(id) values(:loop_var);
```

---

Full code:

```
create or replace table abc(id INT);

create or replace procedure sp7(iteration_limit integer)
returns integer
language sql
as
$$
declare 
    loop_var integer default 0;
begin
    for loop_var in 1 to iteration_limit do
        insert into abc(id) values(:loop_var);
    end for;
end;
$$;

CALL sp7(3);
SELECT * FROM abc;
```

Note: Inserting rows one at a time is not the best from performance standpoint.